# Прописная или строчная?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: "Уполномоченный по правам человека в РФ/уполномоченный по правам человека в РФ"? У Лопатина с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Вы не доверяете Лопатину? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Интересно, что написание прописной или строчной буквы зависит от статуса документа, в котором используются наименования должностей. Думаю, что наименование этой должности в большинстве случаев пишется с маленькой буквы.

1. С прописной буквы в официальных документах пишутся наименования высших должностей и высших почетных званий в России и в бывшем Советском Союзе, например: 
   Президент Российской Федерации, Вице-Президент РФ, Председатель правительства РФ, Главнокомандующий ОВС СНГ, Государственный секретарь;
   Председатель Президиума Верховного Совета СССР, Председатель Совета Министров СССР, Генеральный секретарь ЦК КПСС, Маршал Советского Союза;
   Президент Республики Татарстан, Премьер-министр Республики Адыгея;
   Герой Российской Федерации, Герой Советского Союза, Герой Социалистического Труда, Почетный работник общего образования РФ, Отличник народного образования.

Примечание. ***В документах и текстах неофициального характера, а также при использовании неполного (не официального) наименования, со строчной буквы пишутся названия всех (в том числе и высших) должностей и званий: "...на совещании присутствовали президент РФ, председатель Государственной думы, министры...; Как сообщила пресс-служба главы государства, президент выразил удовлетворение..."***.

1. Наименования **других должностей и званий** (руководителей разных рангов, воинских званий, ученых степеней и званий и др.) пишутся со *строчной* буквы, например: 
   министр просвещения РФ, губернатор (вице-губернатор) Ивановской области, глава администрации Кемеровской области, мэр г. Москвы;
   прокурор Псковской области, государственный советник юстиции 1 (2, 3) класса, председатель Военной коллегии Верховного Суда Российской Федерации, председатель избирательной комиссии Свердловской области, главный федеральный инспектор по Московской области, государственный арбитр;
   главнокомандующий Военно-Морского Флота, командующий войсками, начальник Генерального штаба Вооруженных Сил, маршал авиации (войск связи, инженерных войск);
   президент Российской академии наук, действительный член РАН, член-корреспондент РАН, доктор технических наук;
   народный артист РФ, заслуженный деятель культуры, лауреат Нобелевской премии;
   президент компании, генеральный директор, первый заместитель генерального директора, вице-президент, заместитель главного бухгалтера и т. д.

Примечание: ***Допускается использование прописных букв*** в написании должностей руководителей разных рангов, ***если пишущий хочет выделить слово***, придать ему особое значение (ранговая функция прописной буквы). Так, написание должности Генеральный директор, Президент (Вице-президент) компании (с прописной буквы) часто бывает узаконено Уставом организации, предприятия.(http://www.doc-style.ru/SPR/?id=1.2)

Answer (score 2):

"Названия должностей обычно пишутся со строчной буквы. Прописная используется в названиях высших государственных должностей (Президент РФ, Председатель правительства) только в официальных текстах, документах государственного и международного уровня. В публицистических текстах слово, обозначающее должность, пишется с маленькой буквы (наш президент; премьер-министр). Тенденция писать названия должностей как государственных, так и коммерческих организаций с прописной свидетельствует о желании пишущего подчеркнуть значимость, особое уважение к называемой должности. В некоторых случаях такие ненормативные написания выглядят комично: Главный Бухгалтер ООО; Зам. Директора; Вице-Президент торговой фирмы.

Сложными являются случаи употребления больших букв в составных названиях официальных организаций, органов власти и различных государственных институтов.

Если составное наименование называет высшие правительственные организации и учреждения, а также некоторые международные организации, то каждое знаменательное слово, в соответствии с Правилами 1956 г., должно начинаться с прописной. Например, Государственная Дума; Общественный Совет при Президенте РФ; Верховный Суд; Международный Олимпийский Комитет. Однако справочник под редакцией В.В. Лопатина «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник» (М., 2006) предлагает в официальных названиях органов власти и учреждений с прописной буквы писать только первое слово: Государственная дума; Генеральная прокуратура РФ; Государственный совет. Этот же справочник рекомендует в неофициальных названиях организаций и учреждений писать с прописной первое слово: Государственная дума – Дума; Центральный дом художника (по справочнику Д.Э. Розенталя – Центральный Дом художника) – Дом художника; Российский государственный педагогический университет им. А.И. Герцена – Герценовский университет. Очевидна динамика орфографической нормы в употреблении прописных букв в официальных и неофициальных названиях высших правительственных организаций и учреждений." *(Это с сайта "gramma.ru")*

А это из статьи *Андрея Мирошниченко "Член с большой буквы. О правописании должностей в РФ"*

"Вопрос, надо сказать, не такой простой и всегда имел некоторую политическую подоплеку. Например, наименования высших должностей и почётных званий в СССР писались с большой буквы – Председатель Президиума Верховного Совета, Председатель Совета Министров СССР, Герой Социалистического Труда.

В околонаучных кругах и сейчас идут споры по поводу написания должности президента России. Например, есть такая почти диссидентская по смелости точка зрения, что когда о человеке – надо писать с маленькой. А когда о должности – с большой. Потому что это один из символов государства, наряду с гимном, гербом и флагом. Правда, тогда и Гимн с Гербом и Флагом надо писать с большой. В общем, по поводу президента правописание колеблется. Оно у нас хорошее, как говорил Вини-Пух, но колеблется. Совершенно очевидно, что выбор размера буквы в данном случае является политическим вопросом. Размер имеет политическое значение.

Что любопытно: некоторые орфографические справочники на полном серьезе предписывают своего президента писать с большой буквы, а президентов других стран – с маленькой. Изящно, черт возьми. И сколько всего в этой рекомендации!

А еще можно сказать, что выбор буквы для названия должности является также и инструментом диагностики – это верный маркер предрасположенности к рабству."