# Губернатор или губернатор

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Добрый день! Вопрос следующий: есть ли какое-то правило русского языка о правильном написании слова губернатор. В официальных документах всегда встречаю заглавную букву в любой части предложения, в СМИ - прописную. Это традиция чиновников, или установленная норма русского языка?

Answer (score 4):

С прописной буквы пишутся только в официальных текстах названия высших государственных должностей и титулов, напр.: Президент Российской Федерации, Председатель Правительства РФ.
Наименования же остальных остальных должностей пишутся со строчной буквы: президент, канцлер, председатель, министр, премьер-министр, заместитель министра, мэр, император, королева, хан, шейх, генеральный секретарь, заслуженный деятель культуры, лауреат Нобелевской премии, посол, атташе,  губернатор (вице-губернатор) Ивановской области, и т.д. 
См.[Полный академический справочник](http://orthographia.ru/)

Вопрос также обсуждался [на этом сайте](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6780/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Answer (score 3):

Это чиноничье лебезятничество. Что по Розенталю, что по Лопатину, *губернатор* пишется со строчной буквы. Хотя попадались директивы областного уровня писать про местного губернатора с прописной. Иногда это даже в местных провластных газетах проскальзывает.

Answer (score 0):

Тут и спорить нечего, ответ однозначный - губернатор, т.е. со строчной буквы.